# How to perform RGB->YUV conversion with ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, rgb, yuv

How to perform RGB->YUV conversion with ActionScript?

Libs?
Tuts?
Articles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this article: http://www.fourcc.org/fccyvrgb.php
Conversion is quite easy so you probably could write your own function based on this:

```
Y  =      (0.257 * R) + (0.504 * G) + (0.098 * B) + 16

Cr = V =  (0.439 * R) - (0.368 * G) - (0.071 * B) + 128

Cb = U = -(0.148 * R) - (0.291 * G) + (0.439 * B) + 128
```